# The value does not change in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I made a button to update a user's access to the website and I get an error. I searched here but I did not find the answer to help me, can you give me some advice?
This is the error: Creating default object from empty value

Controller:

```
public function suspendUser(Request $request, $id) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->userAcces = 0;
    $user->save();
    return back();
}
```

View::

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                        <form>
                        <a href="" class="view" title="View" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="/updateUser/{ $row->id }" class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="/delete/{ $row->id }" class="delete" title="delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                        <a href="" class="addFriend" title="Add Friend" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i></a>
                        <form>
</div>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/updateUser/{id}', 'UserController@suspendUser');
```

I tried other things but failed, maybe something went wrong in the controller?

Comment: Did you get id in suspendUser function?? I think  $user is not object means there is not found user data please check it.

Comment: Check the code at each point. First check if the id is being passed to the function. Then check if the find function actually returns an object.

Answer (score 0):

It means this user is not found with this $id and $user is null , so check the $id which sent to the suspendUser method, and it's better to use User::findOrFail($id); in order to return 404 if model not found ,and not face these kinds of errors.